# JWT Token Authentication error caused by incorrect values?

Tags: json, authentication, jwt

Im trying to authenticate to the bullhorn API.
This API uses JWT tokens for authentication.
In the first request I have to create a JWT token.
The JSON I have is this:

```
{
  "claims":{
    "iss":"Connexys",
    "iat":1669996209,
    "exp":1669996509,
    "aud":"",
    "sub":"",
    "publicKey":"[publickey]",
    "domain":"connexys.nl"
 },
    "key":"[secretkey]",
    "alg":"HS256"
}
```

I encode my JSON to a JWT token in https://jwt.io/
Then I do this request in postman:

```
POST https://[company].api.connexys.nl/jwt/auth
Request Headers
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
  Accept: */*
  Host: [company].api.connexys.nl
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Length: 388
Request Body
  requestToken: "[JWT TOKEN]"
```

I should get a bearer token back, but instead I get this error:

```
{
  "timestamp" : "2022-12-02T16:51:04.945",
  "status" : 401,
  "error" : "Unauthorized",
  "message" : "No message available",
  "path" : "/jwt/auth"
}
```

**My question is, what causes this error?**


Are my public or secret keys just incorrect or is it caused by the incorrect exp value?
Im pretty sure the keys are correct.
And what is the **signing key** to verify the signature?
 What do I fill in that value?
Maybe thats the issue, that I didn't verify the signature?

API documentation:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the API documents to send the auth header in the body? if no, then try sending it in request header

Authentication: 'Bearer [your token]'

Comment: The bearer token I want to generate is not returned in the JWT endpoint. I know how to authenticate the API, but without a bearer token its hard

Comment: Can you share the documentation page for bullhorn API for us to look at

Comment: added documentation screenshot, the documentation is at a private location

Comment: The thing is you don't build JWT yourself. You ask an identity server for it. You pass along client id and client secret along with the roles you need the token for. The identity server looks at your credentials and the roles you are asking for. If the roles are granted previously for the client_id then Identity server returns the token

Comment: Are you trying to implement an identity server for the API?

Comment: Refer this page for Bullhorn API http://bullhorn.github.io/REST-Backed-Custom-Components/

Comment: No Im trying to authenticate so I can do calls to get data